# How to traverse extrinsics executed via substrate interface

Tags: substrateinterface

I am interacting with the substrate node using substrate interfact. I am using following command to submit extrinsic to be executed by the runtime:

```
extrinsic = substrate.create_signed_extrinsic(
        call=call,
        keypair=kp_council_first_member
    )

    receipt = substrate.submit_extrinsic(extrinsic, wait_for_inclusion=True)

    if not receipt.is_success:
        print(substrate.get_events(receipt.block_hash))
        raise IOError
```

Like we examine the events after submitting and executing the extrinsic. On the same line, I wanted to examine the properties of the extrinsic executed by this command. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You only created one extrinsic with that, how do you want to examine "all the extrinsics created by this command"? There is only one.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Let me re phrase my question